# Using sed to replace the same text line in multiple files

Tags: bash, sed, centos7

In my current directory (projDir), I have about 41 folders as follows:

- ProgOneDir
- ProgTwoDir
- ProgThreeDir
- ...
- ProgFortyOneDir

...etc (I did not come up with the naming scheme and I am not a systems admin so please don't yell at me for them).

Inside each of the subfolders, there are README.md files I need to edit. Instead of going into each subfolder and editing the files there, I would like to use a sed command to do so. The files are consistently named README.md

I am running CentOS7

My current command is:

```
find . -name 'README.md' -exec sed -i -e 's/./makeprog $MAKE_FLAGS CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include/libtool" OFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib"/./makeprog/g' {} \;
```

Essentially, I need to switch:

```
./makeprog $MAKE_FLAGS CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include/libtool" OFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib
```

to

```
./makeprog
```

Would somebody be able to assist? The error I get is:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 43: unknown option to `s'
```

I have already looked at:

- [Using sed to replace text between strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48074303/using-sed-to-replace-text-between-strings)
- [How to replace a path with another path in sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12061410/how-to-replace-a-path-with-another-path-in-sed)
- Some other online resources

I believe my error is arising with the ./command. I have followed advice of switching all / to +, but that still didn't work, as I got the following error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 110: unterminated `s' command
```

Thank you.

Comment: Hi @kvantour, I don't think it is. I saw that, but it isn't explicitly paths I'm concerned with, it is switching a command that contains ./

I found that article and tried following the advice of switching / to + and it still didn't work.

Comment: Basically you alreay have the correct command. Only failure: The slash character is part of your "pattern", that's why you either must escape it or use another "separator" for sed, for example the # char: `sed 's#./makeprog $MAKE_FLAGS CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include/libtool" OFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib"#./makeprog#g'`

Comment: The slashes give you the error 'unknown option to s`. The other problem is your dollar sign. You have to escape them.

Comment: @kvantour $ signs don't matter as long as using single quotes.

Comment: @rudi, I was confused. I thought `$` had to be escaped due to the anchoring (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_08)

Comment: @kvantour: that's true if `$` is at the end of the regexp. otherwise it's considered as a normal character.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using slash as the delimiter to the `s///` command, but you are putting slashes into the pattern. You can pick a different delimiter that does not appear in the pattern.

Assuming your current directory is projDir, and there is only one call to makeprog:

```
sed -i -E 's#(./makeprog) .*#\1#' */README.md
```

or

```
perl -i -e 's{./makeprog\K.*}{}' */README.md
```

If you want to specifically match that exact line, then:

```
# are you missing a trailing double quote?
line='./makeprog $MAKE_FLAGS CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include/libtool" OFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib'
sed -i -E "s#$line#./makeprog#" */README.md
```

Comment: Hi @glenn jackman, thank you for your answer. This worked perfectly. Might you be able to explain what the .*#\1# is doing, so that I may learn?

Comment: On the left hand side, the regex pattern, I put parentheses around `(./makeprog)`. In the right hand side, the replacement string, you can use `\n` to use the text matched in the `n`th parenthesised group. For documentation see [3.3 The `s` Command](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/The-_0022s_0022-Command.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command)